# How Would You Put A Transition Into The Blender VIdeo Editor?

Tags: animation

I created a transition in Blender. I tested it on OBS to see if it actually works. So, when I put it in the Blender video editor, **it isn't transparent**.* What should I do to make it transparent in the video editor?

*I am using a different video editor than Blender, but I would like to eventually switch. The same thing happened in the other video editor, it isn't transparent. Also, I am new to Blender, so I almost have no clue what I'm doing. (Even though I have had Blender since November of 2020, I haven't used it since.)

Comment: please provide your blend file and show us what you got so far

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE!  Could you please include some more details on the construction of the transition you created in Blender and maybe a screenshot of exactly what isn't working?  It's a little hard to get a solid idea of what your issue is in order to help you without a few more details.

Comment: @Chris https://drive.google.com/file/d/1i1H6w2CaA54uTuaqFyGFFOCgYfvb0SaS/view?usp=sharing

Comment: do you mean something like this? https://youtu.be/n4p41vcj5u0. if yes, i would make a short tutorial for you. Basically you just add a color and a transform strip and then keyframe the offset and rotate and scale the color/transform.